# What are "white" and "gray" in the peer list?

Tags: full-node, peer

When I use the "print_pl" command in simplewallet to see the peer list, the first attribute of each line is either "white" or "gray". What is the meaning of it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

White peers are online and reachable and grey peers are [offline](https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/blob/master/src/p2p/net_node.inl#L1009).

The longer period of time it has been since you last used your daemon, the more grey peers you are likely to see.

White peers that fail to upgrade during a hard fork are (eventually) dropped from the network and become grey. People move and change VPS hosting providers, so peer status will always change over time.

Comment: Is the list of white peers supposed to be an approximation of the list of all currently live peers, or only some subset of that?